# Google Spreadsheets sum formula simplification

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A<>"", P4:P + Q4:Q + R4:R + S4:S + T4:T + U4:U + V4:V + W4:W, ""))

I wanted to simplify it in order not to write `P4:P + Q4:Q + R4:R + S4:S + T4:T + U4:U + V4:V + W4:W` one by one, it is really ugly and a manual work. Asked ChatGPT to simplify it, but it failed, do you you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Replace `that part` of the formula with this:*

```js
byrow(P4:W,lambda(Σ,sum(Σ)))
```

Comment: It does not look like Google Spreadsheets syntax though.

Comment: [byrow](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)

Comment: Wow, I though you were kidding me :D `lambda`, `Σ`, etc... But Actually I can get rid of `ArrayFormula` and write `=BYROW(P4:Z,LAMBDA(row,SUM(row)))`, right @rockinfreaksow?

Comment: If you want to skip total blank rows; a more appropriate version would be `=byrow(P4:Z,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(Σ))))`